# confusion about finite line charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

My physics knowledge is (sadly) very infinitesimal and I have a question about a calculation which I think is wrong, but want to be sure.

I tried to calculate the potential of a finite line charge. According to my understanding, this is simply done by integrating point charges along the line. When I do that, I get something that looks like this (lines are the equipotential lines)

[image: line charge]

This plot makes intuitive sense to me since the potential computation is basically convolving a $1/\|x\|$ function with a "wide" delta pulse which I expect to look like this.

The integration result is

$$\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\varepsilon_{0}}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x_{2}^{2}+\left(a-x_{1}\right)^{2}}+x_{1}-a}{\sqrt{x_{2}^{2}+\left(b-x_{1}\right)^{2}}+x_{1}-b}\right)$$
where $(x_1,x_2)$ are the coordinates where the potenial is computed and (a,b) are the limits of the line charge that lives on the x-axis.

However, many calculations that I found on the web (e.g. [this one](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potlin.html)) obtain a result that is independent of the abscissa. First I thought that their result might only hold for x-values between the ends of the line, but even then the potential should not be independent of the abscissa.

Am I getting something important wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your method of summing up points charges is qualitatively correct, and your image looks good as well. Can you share the functional form of your potential?

Comment: Hi fabee, so not to be elusive but you are on the right track and I think it would be best if I gave you a hint for now. I would draw very careful pictures of both scenarios and label each parameter {x1,x2,a,b}, {a,b,d} and think very carefully about what each means for the relevant case. Right away we can see that there are a different number of parameters between the 2 formulas - what does this mean?

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what you are getting at. Since my line lies on the x-axis, $d=x_2$ while $a$ and $b$ are basically the same (with the slight difference that the other example uses $-a$). The other example gets equipotential lines that are parallel to the x-axis. However, I think this is only true for the bisector of the line charge (i.e. all point which have the same distance to the points (a,0) and (b,0)). This is because all points that don't lie on the bisector get less contribution from one side, therefore, the potential line should bend.

Comment: So what is the analogue of x1 for the potential you linked to?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that their formula doesn't use abscissa variable, equivalent to your $x_1$.  This is because their $a$ and $b$ variables are defined differently.  You may notice that $b$ only ever occurs as $b-x_1$.  Replace that expression with $b$, you'll eliminate $x_1$, and it's likely you will get the formulas to correspond.

Comment: Theres probably a further sign error in front of an $x_1$ if we compare to the [known solution](http://www.problemsinelectrodynamics.com/fs-charge-configurations/linecharge)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate system in the example you cited is kind of strange, since it **defines** the observation point as x=0.  As the observation point changes, both a and b will change (so the variation with x is "hidden").  Your coordinate system looks more rational to me.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that this is the problem. They are basically computing the potential for all points for which $x_1=0$. For any other point, their calculation is not correct.  Thanks for the hint (also to Alan and DJBunk).

Comment: @fabee, you're welcome.  Btw, beautiful graphic.  What tool did you use?